# How to FILTER rows that are not blank?

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet where I am transposing unique values from a data range and displaying them. I only want to include values from rows in column A when the row in column B is `NOT` blank. I've tried using:

```
=not(isblank(A:A))
```

but it didn't work. If possible I want to fit in the function format I already have:

```
=transpose(unique(filter(A:A,(B:B= ....)
```

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
=transpose(unique(filter(A:A, B:B<>"")))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Works for me. I didn't need to have unique values or transposing, so I don't know if that works, but the part of using "filter" to get non-blank rows does.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure nor tested, but this might work as well

(I found it some years ago from a @player0's answer I think, but can't find it again):

```
=Filter(({A1:A;B1:B}),({A1:A;B1:B})<>"")
```

For example, I used the following version.

It removes all non uppercase content cells and intemediary blank cells from Column A:

```
=ArrayFormula(
              Filter(({if(exact(A2:A,upper(A2:A)),A2:A,"")}), 
                     ({if(exact(A2:A,upper(A2:A)),A2:A,"")})<>"")
             )
```

Hope it can help others!

Answer (score 0):

you can use query too:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(QUERY(A:B, "select A where B<>''")))
```